# Sampling from two different datasets for training and testing a model

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis, supervised-learning

I am doing an experiment to test the ability of a neural network model to generalize. I have two datasets of different size. The second dataset is different from the first one, it contains some words that are not in the first dataset. I want to use examples from the first dataset for training and test on examples from the second dataset. Is it correct to take a sample from the first dataset and use this sample as a training set and take a sample from the second dataset and use this sample as a test set? More precisely, if the first dataset contains 66360 examples and the second one contains 56112 examples, can I sample 50000 examples from the first dataset and use those 50000 examples as a training set and sample 50000 examples from the second dataset and use those 50000 examples as a test set?

Comment: The tag ''machine-learning" is used only for Programming or coding related questions for machine learning. So, it would be better if you removed that tag. Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) for more info on this tag

Comment: Why not using all the data?